# How to Get Summary Statistics

Tags: orange

just starting out with Orange and I figured out how to run a linear regression but how do I get at the summary statistics? I can see the coefficients with a Data Table but where's stuff like Adjusted R Square?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python Script widget to print out the adjusted R square. Connect the "Predictor" output from the Linear regression widget to the "in_classifier" input of Python Script and execute

```
print in_classifier.r2adj
```